# count number time a row was selected in from a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, count

I have a basic blog MySql table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blogs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blogText` text NOT NULL,    
  `allowcomment` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I want to keep track of how may times I query each row. Basically keeping tracks of view. I really don't want to create a table to keep track of IP address and insert an Ip address and blogs.id as a unique key. Then count number of unique keys in that table.

I want to be as efficient and accurate as possible.

Comment: Basically, you can't count the number of times a row was selected unless you create a table or column to keep the count, then write the code to update the counter, yourself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a new table or column for keeping count. and use a `trigger` to update count after each select query. That is the way to do, I think.